# how can i create json object from sql query using $wpdb->get_results in wordpress?

Tags: json, wordpress

I want json object in below format.i used ajax to get the data but not get the data in below json format.

```
 {
      "data": [
        [
          "Tiger Nixon",
          "System Architect",
          "Edinburgh",
          "5421",
          "2011/04/25",
          "$320,800"
        ]
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Which is your original data structure?

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_json_encode` function. See more at [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_json_encode/). Or if you use Ajax, use `wp_send_json_success` function at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success).